# Oscilloscope input clippers

Tags: oscilloscope, circuit-protection, input-impedance, voltage-clipping

The analog front end of an oscilloscope begins with an attenuation stage. Mostly they use two attenuation stages, like 1/1 and 1/50.

[image]
<sup>From: [Rigol Homebrew Wiki - schematics page](http://rigol.codenaschen.de/index.php/Schematics)</sup>

The image above belongs to an oscilloscope AFE. Here, a relay sets the attenuation. The attenuation is in the stage of 1/1 in the picture. After the relay and a 330 pF capacitor there is a clipper diode stage.

When the frequency increases, the reactance of the capacitor decreases. When a 50 MHz signal is applied the reactance is 9.64 Ω.

How can clippers stands a 20 Vpp, high-current, 50 MHz signal? What is protecting the +5 V and -5 V lines from the input signal? And how does this protect semiconductors?

Comment: It's your circuit until you demonstrate other wise so, unless you care to share the bigger picture as to where you got the circuit or how you acquired it, it's provenance is going to remain weak. It's a 300 pF by the way. Any image posted does need to be attributed to its source BTW.

Comment: The source added now. For 300pF capacitor for 50MHz signal reactance is 9.64ohm. The question still valid i guess.

Comment: No, that is just a link to the full picture. An attribution links the original source.

Comment: @Andyaka That's a bit unreasonable, as getting the original source involves stealing the schematics from Rigol in China. This hand drawn reverse engineered diagram from the "rigol homebrew wiki" http://rigol.codenaschen.de/index.php/Main_Page is the best source you can hope for, besides tearing down a Rigol DS1052E yourself. Unfortunately none of the schematics on the site show how the +5V and -5V rails are derived, and what kind of protection those have.

Comment: Does the product spec say it will tolerate said overload without damage?

Comment: @Kartman it is not clear in the specs. I guess a signal 20Vpp and 50MHz which  has enough power to overload clippers is very rare so they dont care much? i dont know

Comment: @AhmetAtcı Are you asking about the BAV199 diodes or some other component?

Comment: @AndrewMorton not only BAV99 diodes but also power lines. The input Voltage will reach power lines and harm the components feeding via -5V and +5V rails. what is preventing that?

Comment: @jms I'm just asking for the original source of the hand-drawn schematic and not a link I can click-on that takes me to the picture i.e. where(?) on the web is this diagram held. The fact that it now transpires to be some tear-down of a Rigol scope is a little more troublesome because, there is no evidence that the site that holds the diagram has ever verified that it is correct.

Comment: @Andyaka ,@jms Sorry for the trouble i should have add the source correctly.

Comment: @Kartman the [Rigol DS1052E datasheet](https://beyondmeasure.rigoltech.com/acton/attachment/1579/f-0024/0/-/-/-/-/file.pdf) does not. It only lists a maximum input voltage of 400 V DC + AC, and a measurement category of CAT I 300Vrms, 1000Vpk / CAT II 100Vrms, 1000Vpk. The user manual doesn't go into more detail either. There is no frequency dependent voltage de-rating curve, nor are there different ratings for different input settings. There is a separate 40 V DC + AC rating, but that's for the logic analyzer inputs

Comment: @AhmetAtcı I think the answer may be they cannot. What leads you to believe they can?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes may be they cannot. I wonder what is the reason they didn't put a protection for that range and what is the limit frequencies and power for safe usage? I am designing a litte oscilloscope so I want to have enough protection for the inputs.

Comment: @AhmetAtcı You missed that **essential** part in the question: "*I am designing a litte oscilloscope so I want to have enough protection for the inputs.*" Also, you did not define "enough protection." Please think about how much information we need to begin to help you.

Comment: Why is this getting multiple close votes "questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic"? OP is clearly trying to understand the rationale behind design decisions in a commercial product in order to better design his own. At no point has OP asked how to use an oscilloscope, or what kind of signal can be fed into the inputs without damage. OP has simply seen that the specs don't match with the limitations implicit in the circuit, and is asking why. I can understand closing the question on a different basis, but the "questions about use" rationale doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jms - Hi, What *Andy aka* requested, in terms of a link to the original image source, meant the original source of *that* image copied by the OP - not the source of the "real" scope schematic, since the OP didn't copy *that* into the question here. I hope that makes sense. This is all to comply with the [SE site rule regarding referencing copied/adapted material](/help/referencing). We want the link to be to the HTML webpage, not only to the image, also because any attribution of the image is likely to be on that webpage (as is true in this case) *and* the webpage may contain useful context.